# Crystal Reports - Convert parameter to text

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Version: Crystal Reports 2008

I have a string parameter that has multiple options:

Team 1
Team 2
Team 3...
Team 16

I want to show which team(s) the user selects on the report.

User selected: Team 1, Team 5, Team 6, Team 13

The logic I want to use is:

```
if {?SelectTeam}="All" then "All"
else totext({?SelectTeam})
```

but obviously, that doesn't work.  I have added the parameter to the report and it only shows the first item that is selected.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work since `{?SelectTeam}` should be an array.

```
Local StringVar StrTeams := "";
Local NumberVar i; /FTFY
if {?SelectTeam}="All" then "All"
else (
    For i := 1 To UBound({?SelectTeam}) Do
    (
        StrTeams := StrTeams + {?SelectTeam}[i] + " ";
    );
    StrTeams;
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IIf ({?SelectTeam}="All", "All", Join({?SelectTeam}, " ") )
```